# PHP if statement seems to not compare correctly

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Ok so I am pulling what kind of font is used from my database that is saved from a previous form.  My issue is that even when I 100% replicate what I echo to come from bodyFont it will not compare and just drop to the else statement of error.  What in the world is causing this?  Can it be the fact that I have " and ,?  Any help would be awesome.  (I have to use the full name Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif ETC for what I am doing.

NOTE:

JUST FYI - I have my connection and everything that's not the code giving me a issue, I can pull from the database and also used the same if statement to work for header font but that simply uses words no , or " in names.

```
 <?php
    echo "$bodyFont";
    if ($bodyFont == 'Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif') {
            echo "
            1
            ";
        } elseif ($bodyFont == '"Times New Roman", Times, serif') {
            echo "
            2
            ";
        } else {
            echo "<br />error";
        }
?>

Ran Var_Dump and got the following:
string(56) "Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif" - PULLED FROM DATABASE
string(46) "Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif" - PULLED FROM VAR
```

56 and 46... How would this be fixed?

```
<?php
$one = 'Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif';
$bodyFontstrip = strip_tags($bodyFont);

var_dump($bodyFont);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($one);


    if ($bodyFontstrip == $one) {
            echo "Arial";
        }  else {
            echo "<br />error";
        }
?>
```

OK I SEE WHATS GOING ON:
The `$bodyFont` that I pull form the server turns out as `Arial, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, sans-serif` with the extra `&quot;` in it.  I must find a way to remove this now.

To fix I did as GrumpyCrouton suggested below and used html_entity_decode($bodyFont).

FIXED WORKING CODE:

```
<?php
$one = 'Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif';
$two = '"Times New Roman", Times, serif';
$bodyFontclean = html_entity_decode($bodyFont);

var_dump($bodyFont);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($one);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($two);


if ($bodyFontclean == $one) {
        echo "Arial";
    }  elseif ($bodyFontclean == $two){
        echo "Times";
    } else {
        echo "error...";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: So, what **exactly** does `$bodyFont` contain?

Comment: Where is `$bodyFont` being set, and what appears as a result of `echo "$bodyFont";`?

Comment: `var_dump()` and edit it into this question.

Comment: I stated all that.  I am using the ECHO and what shows in the DATABASE as to what it should = to.  The echo pulls from the database this - Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif and even tho I set it to equal its self it still jumps to error.

Comment: We can't help you if you can't include code that reproduces your problem. You need to post an [MCVE] including real inputs.

Comment: Don't `echo`, instead do `var_dump($bodyFont)`. Is it really *exactly* the same, including preceding and trailing whitespaces?

Comment: `var_dump($bodyFont)` should have only output *one* of those lines. You have two lines of output there, indicating you're running `var_dump` multiple times with multiple different values. The difference in string length indicates there are are likely some non-printing characters in one of your strings. Please update your question to contain the *actual code you're running*, including the additional `var_dump` statements, as well as the exact output your program produces.

Comment: Just do `$bodyFont = html_entity_decode($bodyFont)`

Comment: Don't do that unless you hate yourself ^ or it's a one-time fix

Comment: What would you suggest Joe Phillips instead?

Comment: You are effectively corrupting your data. Imagine if you wanted to use that data for anything that wasn't html related? Too bad, it's already specifically formatted for html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you've inserted HTML encoded values into your database. Don't do this.

You should be HTML encoding stuff on OUTPUT not INPUT.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I'll do that instead!  I used \" on my input.

Comment: For escaping sql, you should be using parameterized queries but that's another topic